# Is there a way to check contacts that have not been used for a long time?

Tags: google-contacts

I have 2k contacts and my phone have a hard time adding more.

I want to delete half of the oldest contacts I no longer use. How do I do so? Is there something like used several times? or last seen?

Not in original google.

But is there an app or web app that allows to do so?

Comment: Software recomendation is fine. However, given that I just want to work with my google account, then web app seems appropriate. It turns out there is an android software for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It takes some work but will get what you want.
Follow these steps for your phone *(you mentioned "Not in original google")*.

- Export all your history and import it in a spreadsheet.
- Also export all your contacts from your phone and import them in the same spreadsheet.
- Compare the two lists and find the contacts missing from your history list.
- **Those missing ones are the ones you probably want to delete**.

If your phone does not support exporting history, install an app like [Phone Vili](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pa.calllog.tracker) *(which is a call history manager)* and do the export through the app.

Although the above steps may take some time and manual handling, I find the procedure safer than the auto ones.

One could also use an app like [Delete Phonebook Contacts: Phone Numbers Eraser](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ProDataDoctor.DeletePhonebookContacts) or [Delete Multiple Contacts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lps.contactremover).
The above mentioned delete apps automate the whole procedure quite a lot.